# CRM deployment Manager , SQL Server is unavailable

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am facing the issue with deployment manager when trying to create new organisation entry. It is giving error " SQL server is unavailable. Below is the brief of my problem:

Earlier application & CRM database was on same server & it was working perfectly fine.

But when we migrated the Database on another server, application was able to connect to database.
but we are not able to add new entry in organiser. When we are trying this it was saying that "SQL Server is unavailable." ( But SQL Server is running fine.)

Note: Firewall is turned off
There is no network issue
SQL Services are running fine

Any help on this would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Yashwant Vishwakarma | www.sqlocean.com

Comment: Which CRM system do you use? And if own system, which programming language/technology?

Answer (score 2):

It could be worth checking [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699806(v=crm.6).aspx) on rehoming / reconfiguring a Dynamics CRM deployment.

I would like to highlight steps 4 through 7 which takes you through updating the registry key of the CRM Server that holds the CRM database connection and updating the CRM organization's database from the Deployment Manager.

Including pertinent parts of the Technet article below with a few minor edits to reflect that this can work not only for SQL Server cluster instances, but also if the databases were simply moved to a new SQL Server and/or SQL Server instance:

On the computer that is running the Microsoft Dynamics CRM web application, click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK.

Locate the following registry subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSCRM

Right-click configdb, and then click Modify.

In the Value data box, change the data source to the name of the new virtual SQL Server (or current SQL Server databases were moved to), and then click OK. For example, the string value in the Value data box should resemble the following:
`Data Source=NewSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MSCRM_CONFIG;Integrated Security=SSPI`

On the computer that is running the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server web application, start Deployment Manager. To do this, click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, and then click Deployment Manager.

Expand the Deployment Manager node, and then click Organizations.

If the organization is not already disabled, right-click the organization, and then click Disable.

WarningWarning
When you disable an organization, users will no longer be able to access Microsoft Dynamics CRM for that organization.
Click Yes to disable the organization.

In the list of organizations, right-click the organization, and then click Edit Organization.

In the Edit Organization Wizard, in the SQL Server box, type the virtual SQL Server name for the SQL Server cluster that you created earlier, and then click Next.  (NOTE:  If not using a SQL Server cluster, just type the SQL Server name or SQL Server name and instance name here).

On the System Requirements page, after a successful diagnostics check, click Next, and then click Apply.

Click Finish.

Enable the organization. To do this, right-click the organization, and then click Enable.

Reset the IIS services on the computer that is running IIS where the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server web application is installed. To do this, click Start, click Run, type iisreset in the Open box, and then click OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure if it helps Yashwant, but I stored it as a reference for myself. Bounty has been rewarded.